# Screen Resolution, Fluid Layouts, Restoring

Tags: resolution, fluid

I love making fluid layouts, but as we all know, one of its problems is that on larger screens, it can cause text to horizontally extend to uncomfortable lengths.

I myself only have a moderate screen size, so I'm wondering this. Do people with gargantuan screens typically restore their window and set it to a more moderate width (multitask), or do they maximize it?

As far as design goes, it's no big deal to set a max width, but still, I just have to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer this either way.

Right now I have my gargatuan screen maximised, later I might not.

Cater for both is your best option, but limit the *fluidness* to a certain max size.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your focus group. "Power" users tend to not run their window maximized while others seem to prefer to have the window maximized.